# How can I influence an Elasticsearch autosuggest query to return an exact match first?

Tags: elasticsearch

Consider the following job titles that are indexed into 3 separate documents:

```
[ "Software Developer Analyst, Senior",
      "Software Developer and Analyst - iOS, iPad, . Net",
      "Software Developer" ]
```

In the real world, we have hundreds of variations for "software developer", so if the autocomplete only returns 10 documents, it's likely buried in noise.

Is it possible to do any sort of ordering to prefer exact matches?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html

Answer (score 0):

Completion suggester use FST (special in-memory data structure that built at index time) for fast searches, so it is possible to influence the results of future queries only at index time (see [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11026) related to your question at GitHub).

In your case you can add [`context`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/suggester-context.html) for your suggester. For example, it could be `category` field which will contain the features of particular software developer. Such features should be somehow retrieved from data that will be indexing:

```
PUT jobs/_doc/1
{
    "suggest": "Software Developer and Analyst - iOS, iPad, . Net",
    "category": ["apple", "ios", "ipad", "dotnet"] 
}
```

And at query time you should try to retrieve such features from user input before send it to ES. For example, if user types "java senior software developer", you transform this input to query

```
POST jobs/_search
{
    "suggest": {
        "jobs_suggestion" : {
            "prefix" : "java senior software developer",
            "completion" : {
                "field" : "suggest",
                "size": 10,
                "contexts": {
                    "category_context": [ "java", "senior" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this approach requires complex preliminary analysis of index data and search queries.

Another option is to assign weights to jobs titles at index time, but it does not fit in your case in my opinion.